# CS0656 Missing compiler required member : exception on run AddEventHandler (missing compiler required member)

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been experiencing this problem on run:

```
Error   CS0656  Missing compiler required member System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler
```

When I look at the line given in the exception it leads me to the XAML declaration of the Click="yourmethod".
This same exception goes for every single 'Click' in my project.

This is just happened and I've no idea why.
If anyone is familiar with the problem and it's solution, please tell me.

**XAML:**

`<Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>`

**If more information is required or my question is incorrectly formatted, please tell me.**

Comment: Where is your code? in which line you're facing that error? why are you trying to run interop?

Comment: I'm getting the errors in lines like this: <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/> only where it has a click listener thanks for your reply

Comment: what's in `HamburgerButton_Click`?

Comment: The problem lies with every single click listener, not only HamburgerButton_Click

Comment: @Prajwal I've approved your edit. When editing, please also remove things like "Thanks" and "Kind regards". (For reference: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333)).

Answer (score 0):

By MSDN reference,

> One of the following problems exists:
>
> • Your installation of the common language runtime is corrupt.
>
> • You have a reference to an assembly that defines a type that is also
> found in the common language runtime. However, your assembly's type
> is not defined the way the C# compiler expects.

So, if you're running it first time, then try reinstalling your Common Language Runtime. If not then check in that `HamburgerButton_Click` method, which might be causing trouble.

MSDN Link | [Compiler Error CS0656](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ed82w55.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem lies in every click listener not only HamburgerButton_Click. And it's not the first time I run the program

Comment: Then re-install CLR and check.